# Lesson 3 - unsure how "sigs" is created or where txInfoSignatories comes from or how it works

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

Spoiler Alert!

The solution for lesson 3 includes the following:

> ```
> {-# INLINABLE mkValidator #-}
> -- This should validate if either beneficiary1 has signed the transaction and the current slot is before or at the deadline
> -- or if beneficiary2 has signed the transaction and the deadline has passed.
> mkValidator :: VestingDatum -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
> mkValidator dat () ctx
>     | (unPaymentPubKeyHash (beneficiary1 dat) `elem` sigs) && (to       (deadline dat) `contains` range) = True
>     | (unPaymentPubKeyHash (beneficiary2 dat) `elem` sigs) && (from (1 + deadline dat) `contains` range) = True
>     | otherwise = False
>   where
>     info :: TxInfo
>     info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx
> sigs :: [PubKeyHash]
> sigs = txInfoSignatories info
>
> range :: POSIXTimeRange
> range = txInfoValidRange info
> ```

It appears that " txInfoSignatories " is a function (functor?) that analyzes " info " which itself is drawn from the script context, but I am at a loss as to where the " txInfoSignatories " code actually comes from. Is there a way to analyze which imported module it is attached to? Is there a way to analyze its code in order to understand what it does? Much of what I am seeing in Haskell seems so opaque, with new features simply appearing and magically doing something, but I am lost as to how I could have analyzed the code/modules/options and come up with this solution on my own.

For the record, here is what I created before I looked at the solution. It compiles without error, but does not behave in the playground as intended.

> ```
> {-# INLINABLE mkValidator #-}
> -- This should validate if either beneficiary1 has signed the transaction and the current slot is before or at the deadline
> -- or if beneficiary2 has signed the transaction and the deadline has passed.
> mkValidator :: VestingDatum -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
> -- mkValidator _ _ _ = False -- FIX ME!
> mkValidator dat () ctx = 
>      ( traceIfFalse "beneficiary 1 - signature missing" signedByBeneficiary1 
>     && traceIfFalse "deadline 1 has passed" deadline1Reached )
>     || (traceIfFalse "beneficiary 2 - signature missing" signedByBeneficiary2 
>     && traceIfFalse "deadline 2 not reached" deadline2Reached )
>   where
>     info :: TxInfo
>     info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx
> signedByBeneficiary1 :: Bool
> signedByBeneficiary1 = txSignedBy info $ unPaymentPubKeyHash $ beneficiary1 dat
>
> signedByBeneficiary2 :: Bool
> signedByBeneficiary2 = txSignedBy info $ unPaymentPubKeyHash $ beneficiary2 dat
>
> deadline1Reached :: Bool
> deadline1Reached = contains (to $ deadline dat) $ txInfoValidRange info
> deadline2Reached :: Bool
> deadline2Reached = contains (from $ deadline dat) $ txInfoValidRange info
> ```

Any Haskell wisdom is much appreciated. I feel like this is more a Haskell knowledge deficit than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TxInfo` is a Record type and one of the fields of the `TxInfo`-record is `txInfoSignatories`. The fields in the records work as "getters". You may refer e.g. to [learnyouhaskell-records](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax) for an example.

The whole definition for `TxInfo` is here:

[image: TxInfo]

It is also completely fine to use the `txSignedBy` helper function as you have done to check whether the given hash is one of the signatories.

Comment: Your answer simply moves my question from  txInfoSignatories   to TxInfo. Where does TxInfo come from? It is not defined in the code for Solution1.hs. If I (in the repl) do ":i TxInfo" or ":t TxInfo" or simply "TxInfo" I get a "variable not in scope" error message. Where does that definition (a very nice and helpful definition to be sure) for TxInfo come from, and how could I have found it on my own?

Comment: It is one of the fields of the ScriptContext ctx, see "info :: TxInfo
    info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx". In repl, do "import Ledger" then ":i TxInfo" and ":i ScriptContext" should work.

Comment: Thank you @MihaiCodescu, I see that now. Is there a way to quickly trace/track these nested types/data/functions/records or is a tedious hunting mission necessary when reverse engineering? BTW, I discovered the :browse command in the repl, which does help.

Comment: @XiTouch It also helps to remember that the validators in the extended UTXO model "see" the whole transaction they are about to validate. In other words: the context where the script is run contains full transaction info. Thus, it is not a big surprise to find TxInfo within ScriptContext.

Comment: I spent a day creating this animation to visualize the connections and sources of each part. Hope this helps anyone else.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLURnogC_kU

Comment: Impressive animation!